# 406 error when attempting to run a sql query with java

Tags: java, json, httpconnection

Hey everyone first time posting so I'm sure I'll miss some stack standards.

Anyways I'm getting a 406 error when attempting to run a sql query with java, even though I'm able to connect without running the sql query (in my code if I take out os.write(queryBody.getBytes()); I will connect, but obviously can't run my sql query.  Any insite on this would be great, I've been testing to see if I did something wrong in my query but it seems to be right. I've also tried REST client but it doesn't support no certification connection. Here is the relevant code:

```
            uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); 
            uc.setDoOutput(true);


            String queryBody = "\"query\":{\"match\": {\"tables\": \"\"}}, \"size\": 50";

            OutputStream os = uc.getOutputStream();

            os.write(queryBody.getBytes());
            os.flush();


            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                int ch = reader.read();
                if (ch==-1) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            }
```

I've been messing around with the line uc.setRequestProperty, but I'm unable to get it working using that. My output when I run uc.getContentType() is "application/json; charset=UTF-8". I've tried the other similar questions on stack but wasn't able to come up with a solution.

Comment: I dont see any SQL here - you want some JSON, get JSON, all fine.

Comment: This is unrelated to SQL. Removing the SQL tag. Please add the SQL code to tag it as SQL.

Comment: Can you explain how trying to run a SQL query through java is unrelated to SQL? The sql code is sent as a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue I changed the line 
uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); 
To
uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");